# Subir dos archivos a PHP mediante un AJAX usando dos botones de adjuntar

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente `html` con dos botones tipo `file`

```
    <label>Adjuntar Recibo de gas escaneado en JPG o PDF</label>    
    <input type='file' name='archivoReciboGas' id='archivoReciboGas' />

    <br></br>   

    <label>Adjuntar Certificado libertad y tradicion en JPG o PDF</label>
    <input type='file' name='archivoCertiLibertad' id='archivoCertiLibertad' />
```

Aqui el `ajax` que envía el archivo pero solo de `1` botón, es decir solo el de cédula , (Subir la cédula)

```
var inputFileCedula = document.getElementById('archivoCedula');
var file = inputFileCedula.files[0];
var data = new FormData();
data.append('archivo',file);
var url = 'php/subir_cedula.php';

$.ajax
({  
    url:url,
    type:'POST',
    contentType:false,
    data:data,
    processData:false,
    cache:false
});
```

Aquí el subir_cedula.php que guarda el archivo

```
<?php
    //PHP QUE SUBE LA CEDULA Y LA GUARDA

    require 'conectar_bd.php';

    $return = Array('ok'=>TRUE);
    $upload_folder ='../archivos_subidos';
    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];

    $tmp_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $archivador = $upload_folder . '/' . $nombre_archivo;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_archivo, $archivador)) {

    $return = Array('ok' => FALSE, 'msg' => "Ocurrio un error al subir el archivo. No pudo guardarse.", 'status' => 'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

De que manera podría aprovechar el mismo `Ajax` para enviar también el archivo que se seleccione del otro botón, es decir los dos al mismo tiempo.

Actualmente debo crear un `AJAX` y un `PHP` para cada botón por separado

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres enviar los dos archivos al mismo tiempo entonces la solución más sencilla es aprovechando el objeto [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/FormData#Parameters) que has creado usando un constructor diferente, indicando el formulario del que obtener los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Como no conozco el nombre ni el id del formulario, obtengo el primero del DOM */
var data = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
var url = 'php/subir_cedula.php';

$.ajax({  
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    processData: false
});
```

Con este código se crearán los datos necesarios para enviar el formulario y todos sus datos (no sólo los archivos) y dependiendo de si se han seleccionado archivos o no, subirán los archivos seleccionados.

En el lado de recepción debes detectar si se ha enviado o no cada uno de los archivos por separado:

```
<?php
/* Muy importante para devolver el resultado correctamente */
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')
require_once 'conectar_bd.php';

/* Almacenamos los errores aquí, ahora podría ser más de uno */
$errores = [];
$upload_folder ='../archivos_subidos';
/* Estos son los campos de archivo que recibiremos */
$campos = [
  'archivoReciboGas',
  'archivoCertiLibertad',
];
/* Repetimos el bucle por cada campo de archivo recibido */
foreach ($campos as $campo) {
  /* Comprobamos que no hubo ningún error durante la subida */
  if (
    isset($_FILES[$campo]['error']) &&
    ($_FILES[$campo]['error'] === 0)
  ) {
    /* ¡OJO! Agujero de seguridad :/ debes filtrar el nombre de archivo
      o fijarlo al identificador de la transacción y, además, comprobar
      que no existe uno que se vaya a sobreescribir */
    if (
      !move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES[$campo]['tmp_name'],
        $upload_folder . '/' . $_FILES[$campo]['name']
      )
    ) {
      $errores[] = "Ocurrió un error al subir el archivo '$campo'. No pudo guardarse.";
    }
  } else {
    $errores[] = "Ocurrió un error al subir el archivo '$campo'. ¿Demasiado grande?";
  }
}
/* Comprobamos si hubo algún error en el proceso */
if (count($errores) > 0) {
  $return = [
    'ok' => false,
    'msg' => implode("\n", $errores),
    'status' => 'error',
  ];
} else {
  $return = [
    'ok' => true
  ];
}
/* Devolvemos el resultado */
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```